# Writing a bash script without using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

We are asked to write a **shell script** which takes in input of **player records** as standard inputs.

**Sample input :**

```
id|name|time
23|Jordan|45:17
14|Jason|4:50
12|Bryan|
24|Cody|00:12
33|kobe|41
55|rocky|0
```

And we need to **read** each **record**(*skip header*) in our script and then **output** each corresponding **record** by converting **time in seconds** and changing **delimiter** from **'|'** to **' '**(*space*).

As we can see in above **sample testcase**, some records have **empty time field**(*3rd record*), for those record **time in seconds** will be considered **0**.

**Sample Case Output :**

```
23 Jordan 2717
14 Jason 290
12 Bryan 0
24 Cody 12
33 kobe 2460
55 rocky 0
```

**my_solution_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash


read -r header
while IFS="|" read -r pid pname time || [[ -n $pid ]]
do  
    min=$(cut -d ':' -f 1 <<< "$time")
    sec=$(cut -d ':' -f 2 <<< "$time")
    ((min*=60))
    ((min+=sec))
    
    echo "$pid $pname $min"
done
```

**Wrong Output :**

```
23 Jordan 2717
14 Jason 290
12 Bryan 0
24 Cody 12
33 kobe 2501
55 rocky 0
```

As we can see above script is giving **wrong output for 5th record**.

> How can I **fix** the **above script**, to get the correct output in
> every case?

I think there might be a simpler solution possible using **awk**, but I don't have much idea about **'awk scripting'** right now,
so I am looking for a way to solve this question using **basic shell commands**, nevertheless **awk command** solutions are also welcome.

**Thank You.**

Comment: `min` and `sec` take on the same value 41 after each `cut`

Comment: You said the input is command line arguments, but you're reading it from standard input. Which is it?

Comment: Don't try to do this with a shell loop - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton That question describes some of the problems, but doesn't suggest many alternatives.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I'm guessing Stephane just wanted to make people aware of the issue but didn't want to recommend any one alternative (and couldn't discuss all of the many possibilities) as that road leads to a religious war :-). The right alternative also depends heavily on what you're doing with the lines you're reading, what's generating them, etc.

Comment: `Writing a bash script without using awk?` is a terrible title for this question - it doesn't describe what you're trying to do at all.

Comment: Your output for kobe is wrong everywhere.

Comment: This might help: `(read h; while IFS='|:' read -r a b c d; do echo "$a $b $((${c:=0}*60+${d:=0}))"; done) < file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cut -d: -f2 <<< "$time"` returns all of `$time` when it doesn't contain a `:` delimiter. So for kobe you're calculating `41*60+41` instead of just `41*60`.

So you need to check whether `$time` contains a `:` before trying to get the seconds.

```
read -r header
while IFS="|" read -r pid pname time || [[ -n $pid ]]
do  
    min=$(cut -d ':' -f 1 <<< "$time")
    if [[ $time =~ : ]]
        sec=$(cut -d ':' -f 2 <<< "$time")
    else
        sec=0
    fi
    ((min*=60))
    ((min+=sec))
    
    echo "$pid $pname $min"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR>1{$3=$3*60+$4; NF=3; print}' FS='[|:]' file
```

Output:

```
23 Jordan 2717
14 Jason 290
12 Bryan 0
24 Cody 12
33 kobe 2460
55 rocky 0
```

`NF=3` limits GNU awk's `print` to three columns.

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Written and tested in https://ideone.com/9RkGvJ

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
FNR==1{  next  }
{
  split($3,arr,":")
  $3=(arr[1]*60)+arr[2]
}
1;
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Setting field separator as `|` for all lines. Then checking `FNR==1` in which putting `next` will skip that line. Then on each line splitting 3rd column with `:` separator and re-creating 3rd field which has 1st element of array multiply with 60 and adding it's 2nd element to it get seconds value in 3rd column. Then mentioning 1 will print lines.

Comment: Just a side note: for people not to get confuse here. Though title of this thread says "without awk solution" but later in thread OP clarifies that awk solutions are also welcome, just adding this here.

Answer (score 2):

An immediate fix is to set minutes to zero if there is no colon in the value. You can avoid the ugly and moderately expensive external processes entirely.

```
sec=${time#*}
min=${time%:"$sec"}
min=${min:-0}
```

This uses the shell's built-in parameter expansion facility to pick apart the value. Briefly, `${time#pattern}` returns the value of `$time` without any prefix which matches `pattern`; the `%` operator does the same for suffixes.

Using an Awk script is almost certainly a better idea; you should be able to learn the basics in less than an hour, perhaps already enough to solve this problem yourself. Here's a quick and dirty untested attempt.

```
awk -F '|' 'NR>1 && ($3 ~ /:/) {m = s = $3;
    sub(/:.*/, "", m); sub(/.*:/, "", s);
    $3 = m*60+s } 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

bash:

```sh
{
  read header
  while IFS='|' read -r id name time; do
    IFS=':' read -r mins secs <<<"$time"
    echo "$id $name $((60 * 10#$mins + 10#$secs))"
  done
} < file
```

We're using the pattern `IFS=delim read -r field1 field2 ...` twice here to do the parsing.

The `10#` in the arithmetic expression is to force the values to be interpreted as base-10 numbers. Otherwise, 08 and 09 will be interpreted as invalid octal numbers due to the leading zero.

Comment: last line doesn't have '\n' newline character, so I guess we need to handle that using `while IFS='|' read -r id name time || [[ -n $pid ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* the other fields won't have an embedded colon, you can parse min & secs on the read, then use parameter parsing default zeroes for empty min or secs. You can also do all the math in one pass, inside the `echo`.

```
read -r header
while IFS="|:" read -r pid pname min secs || [[ -n $pid ]]
do echo "$pid $pname $(( 10#${secs:-0} + 10#${min:-0}*60 ))"
done
```

If names can have colons, this doesn't work.

As pointed out, leading zeroes would also cause issues, so I added a base-selection indicator (`10#`) to assure base-10 math. c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: I think this will give time in minutes for the 5th record as `33 kobe 41`, where as I want time in seconds as `33 kobe 2460`.

Comment: And this solution is not going to work if time format is like `08:56`, as mentioned by @glennjackman

Comment: AH - I assumed a field with no colon was seconds only. My mistake. That makes it even easier.